# Repairing pdfs with damaged xref table

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript

Are there any solutions (preferably in Python) that can repair pdfs with damaged xref tables?

I have a pdf that I tried to convert to a png in Ghostscript and received the following error:

**** Error:  An error occurred while reading an XREF table.
   **** The file has been damaged.  This may have been caused
   **** by a problem while converting or transfering the file.

However, I am able to open the pdf in Preview on my Mac and when I export the pdf using Preview, I am able to convert the exported pdf.

Is there any way to repair pdfs without having to manually open them and export them?

Comment: Depending on the type of damage, pdfrw might be able to fix it.  (I am the pdfrw author.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried using pdfrw to read in the pdf but got an 'PdfParseError: Expected "xref" keyword or xref stream object'. I'm trying to repair this pdf: [here](http://www.filedropper.com/agilenttechnologiesaccounts2015)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to analyze why pdfrw doesn't work.  Meanwhile, I find that pdftk will fix it, e.g. `pdftk srcfile output dstfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file renders as expected in Ghostscript then you can run it through GS to the pdfwrite device and create a new PDF file which won't be damaged.

Preview is (like Acrobat) almost certainly silently repairing the problem in the background. Ghostscript will be doing the same, but unlike other applications we feel you need to know that the file has a problem. Firstly so that you know its broken, secondly so that if the file renders incorrectly in Ghostscript (or indeed, other applications) you know why.

Note that there are two main reasons for a damaged xref; firstly the developer of the application didn't read the specification carefully enough and the file offsets in the xref are correct, but the format is incorrect (this is not uncommon and a repair by GS will be harmless), secondly the file genuinely has been damaged in transit, or by editing it.

In the latter case there may be other problems and Ghostscript will try to warn you about those too. If you don't get any other warnings or errors, then its probably just a malformed xref table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, Ghostscript is unable to process/repair the pdf. However, Preview is able to. I am pulling the pdfs through an API which is known to return corrupt pdfs. So I'm just looking for a way to repair these pdfs in an automated way because I am processing a large quantity of them.

Comment: I'd be curious to see such a PDF file, where possible we try to repair PDFs. Can you manufacture one which you can make public ?

Comment: [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/agilenttechnologiesaccounts2015) you go.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think its the xref at fault (though that is wrong), it appears to be a corrupted image. I'll poke at it further, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Amusing. The file has an image, which declares its length as an indirect object (it does all the pages this way, and all the images). The indirect object declares the length to be 0..... So Ghostscript reasonably complains that the image doesn't have enough data. BTW Acrobat offers to save the file on exit, which pretty much proves its broken, even though it reads it OK. If this is produced by a reasonably recent version of libtiff you should probably raise a bug report with the libtiff developers. (or upgrade if there's a newer version, which it looks like there is)

Comment: FWIW a colleague tried the current libtiff which produced a valid PDF file. Of course, that may not be manufactured the same way, but it suggests that upgrading might help.

Comment: OK, if you can build Ghostscript from source, or at least have the source tree, then you can fix this. In /ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_base.ps at about line 895 is "dup /Filter undef" If you change that to "dup /Length undef" and rebuild, or run Ghostscript and specify the resource folder using "-I<prefix>/ghostpdl/Resource/Init" then Ghostscript will process these files without problem (it will still whinge).

Comment: And finally (honest), if you use MuPDF it can repair the file for you. The command line "mutool -clean -gggg -s <filename.pdf> out.pdf" produced a working file for me.

Comment: Thanks for digging in! I ended up just doing system call to MuPDF in my Python script.

Comment: FWIW I just committed a change to the Ghostscript source which allows Ghostscript to read files like this, so this particular type of file will now work.

Answer (score 2):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

Simply opening and writing a PDF in `borb` should fix some of the corrupt PDF documents (including fixes to a corrupt XREF).

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF

from pathlib import Path
import typing

def fix_pdf(in_path: Path, out_path: Path) -> None:
   doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
   with open(in_path, "rb") as fh:
       doc = PDF.loads(fh)
   with open(out_path, "wb") as fh:
       PDF.dumps(fh, doc)
```

`borb` is an open source, pure Python PDF library that creates, modifies and reads PDF documents. You can download it using:

```
pip install borb
```

Alternatively, you can build from source by forking/downloading the [GitHub](https://www.github.com/jorisschellekens/borb) repository.

Comment: Warning! borb is under AGPL! Be careful

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of your comment. The author of the question does not specify any limitations with regards to licensing. Your comment is (to me at least) the equivalent of saying "warning, this library takes up X Mb" when the author never expressed a memory-concern in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

i know im super late but, if you try...

```bash
cat my.pdf > temp.pdf && hexdump temp.pdf > newpdf.pdf
```

or

```bash
zip my.pdf && unzip my.pdf
```

if you opened the document in...

> *utf-8 read mode*

...then you probably changed some key bytes around, specifically the octal **011**, hexadecimal **0A**, decimal **10**... these are the line feed or *"new line"* characters and they are essential to documentation in *ascii* encoding.

You can hexdump the octal or hexadecimal line strings with hexdump, all-search the document for bad newline characters and change them back to ascii newline.
Be sure to open the document in encoding='ascii' or in bytes mode. your have to get out a character matrix...

If heard of people just compressing the file with zip and uncompressing it to fix this problem as well.

Whenever fiddling around in a pdf, first make a new copy, then fiddle it.

***TL;DR***

```
on line 17 of your document 
you hit a << or ascii 'Line/page Separator' character. 
The guilleme or double chevron isnt used for 
that in UTF-8, your reader panicked and raised an error
```

PDF was written in postscript. If you want to learn how to go crazy on a pdf, i recommend learning postscript.
[This forbidden text is a good start](https://www.adobe.com/jp/print/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)

Comment: There is 0 chance that either of your suggestion solve any thing. `cat my.pdf > temp.pdf` just copies content, including wrong `0x0A` or `0x0D`, or whatever that could be in. And `hexdump temp.pdf > new.pdf` will create an ascii file that is not pdf at all, and won't be readable by no pdf viewer. As for "zip then unzip", it can't alter the content (what an outrage it would be if zip/unzip were altering CONTENTS of the files!). Sorry for the image, but your answer is the computer equivalent of "I heard that snake oil can cure ingrown nail". There is no basis to it. And I swear you didn't try it